# Pandas rolling idmax for True/False rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm keeping score in a True/False column when determining whether some signal is below the background level, so for example

```
sig  bg   is_below
5    3    False
5    3    False
5    3    False
2    3    True   # "False positive"
4    3    False
4    3    False
0    3    True   # Signal is dead and not returning from this point onwards
0    3    True
0    3    True
0    3    True
0    3    True
```

But as I've shown, noise may sometimes generate "false positives", and smoothing the data doesn't get rid of some big spikes, without oversmoothing smaller data. I'm sure there's a proper mathematical way, but perhaps that would be overkill in work and computational efficiency.

Instead, how do I determine the index of the first `True` where `True` appears e.g. 3 times in a row?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I just remembered that True/False could just as easily be interpreted as 1/0, and so a rolling median, e.g.

```
scipy.signal.medfilt(df["is_below"], kernel_size = 5).argmax()
```

Would return the index of the first time encountering `[False, False, True, True, True]`, as the median of `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]` is the smallest window that returns 3 `True` in a row.

I don't know if there is an even better way, but given that I have 100s of datapoints in my timeseries, the returned `argmax` index is accurate enough for my application.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in a pandas dataframe (say called `df`), you can do it by creating a boolean variable `b` which is `True` at each row only when the row and previous two rows are True in `df.is_below`.

```
b = ((df.is_below == True) & (df.is_below.shift(-1) == True) & (df.is_below.shift(-2) == True))
```

Here, `df.is_below.shift(-1)` shifts the whole dataframe back by 1, so we are looking at the previous row (and similarly for `shift(-2)` to look at the row before the previous row).

Full code below:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
sig = [5, 5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
df['sig'] = sig
df['bg'] = [3] * len(sig)
df['is_below'] = df.sig < df.bg

# Find index of first consecutive three True in df.is_below
b = ((df.is_below == True) & (df.is_below.shift(-1) == True) & (df.is_below.shift(-2) == True))
idx = df.index[b][0]  # first index where three Trues are in a row
```